# Differentiation under the Integral sign?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

*[edit: information in the picture]*
\begin{align*}
V&=\int_{0}^{5}\pi\left(\frac{6y}{\sqrt{1+y^3}}\right)^2dy=\pi\int_{0}^{5}\frac{36y^2}{1+y^3}dy\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{5}\frac{12(3y^2)}{1+y^3}dy\\
&=12\pi\int_{0}^{5}\frac{d}{dy}(1+y^3)\frac{1}{1+y^3}dy\\
&=12\pi\left[\ln(1+y^3)\right]_{0}^{5}\\
&=12\pi(\ln 126)
\end{align*}

What is occurring between Steps $(2)$ and $(4)$ within this solution? Is this differentiating under the integral? I personally would not think it is directly so, since there is no partial deriviative. There was no other explanation given with this. Could someone more knowledgeable with integration help? Thanks

Comment: This person is just letting $u=1+y^3$ and differentiating it.

Comment: Your title usually refers to [a different technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. If $f(y)=\ln (1+y^{3})$  then $f'(y)=\frac 1 {1+y^{3}} \frac d {dy} {(1+y^{3})}$ (by Chain Rule) and $\int_0^{5} f'(y)dy=f(5)-f(0)$.

Comment: Right, so they differentiate both sides? Wouldn't this give the answer to dV/dy though?

Comment: They aren't differentiating both sides. They are just rewriting $3y^2$ as $\frac{d}{dy}(1+y^3)$. @bio

Comment: So then how is this related to the chain rule?

Comment: What do you mean? Geetha is differentiating $\ln(1+y^3)$, which involves the Chain Rule, and using FTC from there. @bio

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I had mistaken the explanation of the chain rule with the whole function instead. Thanks